# non-isotopic but homotopic tight contact structure

Tags: 3-manifolds, contact-geometry

By a theorem of Eliashberg, two overtwisted contact structures on a 3-manifold which belong to the same homotopy class (as plane fields), are also isotopic (through contact structures). Is there an example known of two non-isotopic but homotopic tight contact structures on a contact 3-manifold?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there are known examples.  See for example Corollary 1.3C of [this paper](http://resolver.sub.uni-goettingen.de/purl?GDZPPN002069210) of Eliashberg and Polterovich for an infinite sequence of examples on $T^3$.  There is also a short paper of [Akbulut and Matveyev](http://msp.org/pjm/1998/182-2/p01.xhtml) giving examples on homology spheres.  There may also be other examples known from the classification results of Giroux and Honda.

Answer (score 6):

There are indeed many examples and one could cite a lot of papers but if you are interested in the history of this question then j.c.'s answer is not completely correct.

The first example is in Giroux's 94 paper [Une structure de contact, même tendue, est plus ou moins tordue](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASENS_1994_4_27_6_697_0) (which is explicitly cited by Eliashberg and Polterovich).